# Does ARM and Intel intrinsics use the same subkey schedule for AES?

Tags: c, encryption, aes, intrinsics

I'm trying to cut-in an AES implementation on ARMv8 using intrinsics. I have a C++ implementation, and I have an Intel intrinsics implementation.

The implementations are supposed to be equivalent, so I am trying to use Intel as a blueprint for ARMv8. There are some differences, but they are accounted for. The problem is, I'm getting different results.

```c
void AES_encrypt(const Byte *in, Byte *out, const RoundKey *rdkeys, unsigned int rounds)
{
#if defined(__ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO)

    uint8x16_t data = vld1q_u8(in);

    // AES encryption with ARM intrinsics:
    // rnds-1 (9 for AES128) cycles of AES:
    // (Add, Shift, Sub) plus Mix Columns
    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<rounds; ++i)
    {
        // AES single round encryption
        data = vaeseq_u8(data, rdkeys[i]);
        // AES mix columns
        data = vaesmcq_u8(data);
    }
    // One round of encryption: AES, no Mix Columns
    data = vaeseq_u8(data, rdkeys[i++]);
    // Final Add (bitwise Xor)
    data = veorq_u8(data, rdkeys[i]);
    vst1q_u8(out, data);

#elif defined(__AES__)

    __m128i data = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)in);
    data = _mm_xor_si128(data, rdkeys[0]);
    for (unsigned int i=1; i<rounds-1; ++i)
    {
        data = _mm_aesenc_si128(data, rdkeys[i]);
    }
    data = _mm_aesenc_si128(data, rdkeys[rounds-1]);
    data = _mm_aesenclast_si128(data, rdkeys[rounds]);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)out, data);

#endif
}
```

At this point, I am trying to side step subkey calculation. I use the same set of round keys for both implementations:

```c
#if defined(__ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO)
typedef uint8x16_t RoundKey;
typedef uint8_t Byte;
#elif defined(__AES__)
typedef __m128i RoundKey;
typedef uint8_t Byte;
#endif

// Avoid subkey scheduling at this point
RoundKey rdkeys[ROUNDS+1];
for (size_t i=0; i<COUNTOF(rdkeys); ++i)
    memset(&rdkeys[i], (i<<4)|i, sizeof(RoundKey));
```

However, I am arriving at different results. Here's what the dumps produced:

***Intel AES-NI***:

```
In: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
...
Key: 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
Data: 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07
...
Key: 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
Data: 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33
Key: AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA
Data: 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69
...

Out: 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69
```

***ARMv8 AES***:

```
In: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
...
Key: 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
Data: C5 C5 C5 C5 C5 C5 C5 C5 C5 C5 C5 C5 C5 C5 C5 C5
...
Key: 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
Data: C3 C3 C3 C3 C3 C3 C3 C3 C3 C3 C3 C3 C3 C3 C3 C3
Key: AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA
Data: F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9
...
Out: F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 B1 FF B9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9
```

I keep scratching my head over the results. Adding more printf's is not helping identify the problem. I'm beginning to think Intel and ARM intrinsics use a different subkey schedule.

Does ARM and Intel intrinsics use the same subkey schedule for AES?

---

The image below is from a [paper by Cynthia Crutchfield](http://csus-dspace.calstate.edu/bitstream/handle/10211.3/131463/CRUTCHFIELD.pdf). It examines the mappings of Intel intrinsics and ARM intrinsics.

[image]

---

Below is the full program. The command lines to build them are also listed.

***Intel***:

```
g++ -Wall -maes aes-test.cxx -o aes-test.exe
```

***AEMv8***:

```
 g++ -Wall -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mtune=cortex-a53 aes-test.cxx -o aes-test.exe
```

***Program***:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#if defined(__ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO)
# include <arm_neon.h>
# include <arm_acle.h>
#elif defined(__AES__)
# include <wmmintrin.h>
# include <emmintrin.h>
#endif

#if defined(__ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO)
typedef uint8x16_t RoundKey;
typedef uint8_t Byte;
#elif defined(__AES__)
typedef __m128i RoundKey;
typedef uint8_t Byte;
#endif

#define COUNTOF(x) (sizeof(x)/(sizeof(x)[0]))

static const unsigned int ROUNDS=10;
void AES_encrypt(const Byte *in, Byte *out, const RoundKey *rdkeys, unsigned int rounds);
void AES_decrypt(const Byte *in, Byte *out, const RoundKey *rdkeys, unsigned int rounds);

void Print(const char* label, const Byte *in, size_t len, bool lf=false)
{
    if (label)
        printf("%s: ", label);

    for (size_t i=0; in && i<len; ++i)
        printf("%02X ", in[i]);    
    printf("\n");

    if (lf)
        printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Byte cipher[16], recover[16];
    const Byte plain[16] = {
        0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
        0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF
    };

    // Avoid subkey scheduling at this point
    RoundKey rdkeys[ROUNDS+1];
    for (size_t i=0; i<COUNTOF(rdkeys); ++i)
        memset(&rdkeys[i], (i<<4)|i, sizeof(rdkeys[i]));

    AES_encrypt(plain, cipher, rdkeys, ROUNDS);

    return 0;
}

void AES_encrypt(const Byte *in, Byte *out, const RoundKey *rdkeys, unsigned int rounds)
{
    Print("In", in, 16);

#if defined(__ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO)

    // Load the block
    uint8x16_t data = vld1q_u8(in);

    Print("Data (in)", (Byte*)&data, 16, true);

    // AES encryption with ARM intrinsics:
    // rnds-1 (9 for AES128) cycles of AES:
    // (Add, Shift, Sub) plus Mix Columns
    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<rounds; ++i)
    {
        // AES single round encryption
        data = vaeseq_u8(data, rdkeys[i]);
        // AES mix columns
        data = vaesmcq_u8(data);

        Print("Key", (Byte*)&rdkeys[i], 16);
        Print("Data", (Byte*)&data, 16, true);
    }

    Print("Key", (Byte*)&rdkeys[i], 16);

    // One round of encryption: AES, no Mix Columns
    data = vaeseq_u8(data, rdkeys[i++]);

    Print("Data", (Byte*)&data, 16, true);

    // Final Add (bitwise Xor)
    data = veorq_u8(data, rdkeys[i]);

    Print("Data (xor)", (Byte*)&data, 16);

    // Store the output data
    vst1q_u8(out, data);

#elif defined(__AES__)

    __m128i data = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)in);

    Print("Data (in)", (Byte*)&data, 16);

    data = _mm_xor_si128(data, rdkeys[0]);

    Print("Key", (Byte*)&rdkeys[0], 16);
    Print("Data (xor)", (Byte*)&data, 16, true);

    for (unsigned int i=1; i<rounds-1; ++i)
    {
        data = _mm_aesenc_si128(data, rdkeys[i]);

        Print("Key", (Byte*)&rdkeys[i], 16);
        Print("Data", (Byte*)&data, 16, true);
    }
    data = _mm_aesenc_si128(data, rdkeys[rounds-1]);

    Print("Key", (Byte*)&rdkeys[rounds-1], 16);
    Print("Data", (Byte*)&data, 16, true);

    data = _mm_aesenclast_si128(data, rdkeys[rounds]);

    Print("Key", (Byte*)&rdkeys[rounds], 16);
    Print("Data", (Byte*)&data, 16, true);

    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)out, data);

#endif

    Print("Out", out, 16);
}
```

Comment: I noticed the difference in the data values seems to be either 0x90 (90) and 0xBE (190)... (eg. 0xF9 - 0x69, 0xC3 - 0x33, etc.) maybe that will help narrow the issue down perhaps... The out for ARM looks a bit weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does ARM and Intel intrinsics use the same subkey schedule for AES?

It appears the answer is yes. I still need to test against real key scheduling, but I was able to produce the same result with both Intel and ARMv8 intrinsics using the same key schedule.

It looks like there was an off-by-one in Crutchfield's reference implementation. It should have used `rounds-1`, not `rounds` as loop control. It meant I was testing ARMv8 with 11 rounds, not 10. I should have suspected it when the ARMv8 code produced `F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 B1 FF B9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9` instead of `F9 F9 ... F9 F9`.

Here's the updated code:

```cxx
void AES_encrypt(const Byte *in, Byte *out, const RoundKey *rdkeys, unsigned int rounds)
{
#if defined(__ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO)

    uint8x16_t data = vld1q_u8(in);

    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<rounds-1; ++i)
    {
        data = vaeseq_u8(data, rdkeys[i]);
        data = vaesmcq_u8(data);
    }

    data = vaeseq_u8(data, rdkeys[i++]);
    data = veorq_u8(data, rdkeys[i]);

    vst1q_u8(out, data);

#elif defined(__AES__)

    __m128i data = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)in);
    data = _mm_xor_si128(data, rdkeys[0]);

    unsigned int i;
    for (i=1; i<rounds-1; ++i)
    {
        data = _mm_aesenc_si128(data, rdkeys[i]);
    }

    data = _mm_aesenc_si128(data, rdkeys[i++]);
    data = _mm_aesenclast_si128(data, rdkeys[i]);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)out, data);

#endif
}
```

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - Yes, the code is now running. I checked it in on my testing branch at [Fix ARMv8 AES Encryption](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp/commit/701ec3aa1f45a754) and [Fix ARMv8 AES Decryption](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp/commit/14590423249d). I'll push it to Master once it gets through testing. Its running at about 2.8 to 3.0 cpb. Its about 1.0 cpb slower than other top performers, but it beats 30-45 cpb for C++.